# How is the action of scalar ring $S$ on $M\otimes_R N$ well-defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $\sum^k m_i \otimes n_i  = \sum^l m_j' \otimes n_j'$ be two representations of the same tensor in the abelian group $M \otimes_R N$, where $M$ is an $(S,R)$-bimodule and  and a left $R$-module.  How is the action of $S$ on $M\otimes_R N$, defined by

$$
s(\sum^k m_i \otimes n_i) = \sum^k (s m_i)\otimes n_i
$$

well-defined?  I'm having trouble proving that.  The purpose is to show that $M \otimes_R N$ has a natural left $S$-module structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** You could use the universal property of the tensor product.

Let's look at $\ell_s:M\times N\to M\otimes_R N$ where $\ell_s(m,n):=(sm)\otimes n$. It's definitely well-defined since the module operation on $M$ is well-defined. What other properties does this map have?

Of course after all is said and done we're going to relabel $\ell_s(m,n)$ as $s(m,n)$. I just want you to concentrate on left multiplication by $s$ as a function.

Comment: So $\ell_s$ is an $R$-balanced map from $M\times N$ into $M\otimes_R N$.  So there is a group hom $\Phi : M\otimes_R N \to M\otimes_R N$ such that $\ell_s  = \Phi \circ \iota$, where $\iota : M \times N \to M \otimes_R N: (m,n) \mapsto m \otimes n$.

Comment: Then $\ell_s(m,n) = (sm) \otimes n = \Phi \circ \iota (m,n) = \Phi(m \otimes n)$

Comment: @EnjoysMath Right: and you can check that further $\ell_{st}=\ell_s\ell_t$ and $\ell_{s+t}=\ell_s+\ell_t$.

Comment: Dear @EnjoysMath : Sorry if my solution wasn't obvious or elegant enough!

Answer (score 2):

It is sufficent to show that $s( m \otimes n) = (s m)\otimes n$. As you know, we mean from $m \otimes n$ is $(m,n)+L$ where $L$ is $\rm{Im}\otimes$.

Now, for showing  $s( m \otimes n) = (s m)\otimes n$:

$s( m \otimes n) =s(m,n)+L=(sm,n)+L=(s m)\otimes n$

Answer (score 2):

Don't use elements, because then you will miss the obvious and elegant proof: $M$ is an $(S,R)$-bimodule, this means that we have an right $R$-linear map $S \otimes_R M \to M$ satisfying the usual axioms. The tensor product is associative (this is what happens in rschwieb's answer, but why proving this once again in a special case?) and functorial, hence we get an additive map
$$S \otimes_R (M \otimes_R N) \cong (S \otimes_R M) \otimes_R N \longrightarrow M \otimes_R N.$$
The left $S$-module axioms can be checked using diagram cases. In fact, the whole construction works in an arbitrary *cocomplete tensor category*: If $R,S,T$ are algebra objects (sometimes also called monoid objects), $M$ is some $(S,R)$-bimodule object and $N$ is some $(R,T)$-bimodule object, then $M \otimes_R N$ carries the structure of an $(S,T)$-bimodule object (does someone have a reference to the literature for this? I don't want to prove such trivialities in my thesis).

Comment: Dear @Martin : What follows is admittedly unsolicited advice with no offense intended. But I do think it might come in handy for your future interactions with people. Objectively speaking, this is an instructive and advanced example in fluency with the mathematics at hand. On the other hand it has also slipped into self-aggrandizement with terms like "obvious and elegant," and could alienate or amuse (in a bad way) students. That said, it is fair to say *you might miss this insight*, and it is *efficient* but *high-powered.* Something to think about when choosing words. Regards:

Comment: (Also incidentally "obvious" seems like unflattering praise for a truly elegant proof.)

Comment: Dear Martin : I see that you misunderstood and insist on applying my criticism to the contents of the proof (which I praised and still praise.) You missed that I'm applying your description of the proof, not the proof itself. If you try to reflect on the word choices again, I'm sure you will eventually agree. I am just trying to help you sound less out-of-touch with your audience. I *agree* that this solution has instructive insight, but it suffers a little from the intrusion of self you imposed. Again, regards:

Comment: [deleted the comment because obviously I have misunderstood your comment; thanks rschwieb]

Comment: Dummit & Foote is probably a good reference for those statements.

Comment: @Enjoys: Are you sure? I mean the generalization to tensor categories.

Comment: certainly not in dummit and foote, which is very low level