# A question regarding tensor products from Vakil's notes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Vakil's notes have the following exercise:

> If $M$ is an $A$-module and $A\to B$ is a morphism of rings, give $B\otimes_A M$ the structure of a $B$-module.

I don't understand how to do this. How would $b'(b\otimes_A m$) be defined, for instance, where $b',b\in B$ and $m\in M$?

Comment: b′(b⊗m)=(b'b⊗m)

Comment: But as per the definition of tensor products, shouldn't $b'(b\oplus m)=(b\oplus b'm)$ too, which would not make sense?

Comment: @Seth- The comment above was directed at you.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan How does that come from the definition of tensor products?  Hint: it doesn't.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an example makes this more clear. Let $A=\mathbb{Z}$, and $B=\mathbb{C}$, with the map $A\rightarrow B$ being the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Now let $M$ be the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$, which is clearly a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Then

$$ B\otimes_A M = \mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}[X,Y] \cong \mathbb{C}[X,Y], $$

and $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ is clearly a complex vector space, i.e. a module over $\mathbb{C}$. So tensoring by $\mathbb{C}$ has the effect of enlarging the coefficient ring $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. The same sort of thing happens in the general case.

As was pointed out in the comments, for $b,b'\in B$ and $m\in M$, $b'(b\otimes m)$ would be by definition $b'b \otimes m$. The point is that buffing up the elements $m\in M$ to those of the form $b\otimes m \in B\otimes_A M$ allows one to multiply them by $B$ on the left side of the pure tensors.

In the example with $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$, using the tensor notation $b\otimes m$, we can write elements of $\mathbb{C} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ as linear combinations of pure tensors of the form $z\otimes p(x)$, where $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$. So in this notation for example $X^2 + (3+2i)X + iY$ would be $1\otimes X^2 + 3\otimes X + 2i\otimes X + i\otimes Y$. And for an example of multiplication we have say: $i(3\otimes X + i\otimes Y) = 3i\otimes X + i^2 \otimes Y = 3i\otimes X - 1 \otimes Y$, which in the usual notation just says $i(3X+iY)=3iX-Y$.

Comment: My basic concern is that how would $B\otimes_A M$ even be defined?? When one says $X\otimes_A Y$, don't both $X$ and $Y$ have to be $A$-modules?

Comment: $B$ is an $A$-module via the map $\phi: A\rightarrow B$. Given $a\in A$, and $b\in B$, you have $a\cdot b = \phi(a)b$.